# Generating code coverage of REST APIs written in java through mocha tests

Tags: java, api, automation, mocha.js, code-coverage

I have REST APIs written in **java**. I am using **mocha(javascript)** to automate those rest apis. 
Is there any way I can come up with the code coverage report?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can. There are different code coverage tools available. One of them I know is Jacoco. You would need to start the Java app with [Jacoco agent](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html), provide appropriate JVM arguments and run your mocha tests. Jacoco agent instruments with your app and calculates the coverage. At the end of JVM, reports will be generated for you as per the documentation mentioned in the link. Similarly other tools could be used to similar effect.